# Weird behavior with tabular and expl3 integers

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

I'm trying to dynamically generate the data within a `tabular`, and things get weird with an integer I'm using, as it gets reset to zero IFF I emit a column separator.  (Awful) code follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_X

\begin{tabular}{cc}

\int_set:Nn \l_X {2}
\makebox[0.095in]{\int_use:N \l_X}&
\makebox[0.095in]{\int_use:N \l_X}\\

\end{tabular}
\\
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\int_set:Nn \l_X {2}
\makebox[0.095in]{\int_use:N \l_X}
\makebox[0.095in]{\int_use:N \l_X}\\

\end{tabular}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The first `tabular` output is `2 0`. The second's is `2 2`.

Why is the integer value changing across a column separator?

Comment: a table cell is a group like `{...}` so the setting is discarded at the `&`

Comment: Ah! Unsaid is that replacing `\int_set` with `\int_gset` will get the desired behavior in this case. I learned something today! Thanks, @DavidCarlisle!

Comment: yes but then you should not use `\l_...` as the variable. Also the construct can not be nested in tables or other places as the nested uses will globally mess up the outer ones